# Weird open string sound

Tags: classical-guitar

As I play one of the strings openly, without pressing any fret, this annoying sound occurs. Why is it happening and how can I fix it? http://picosong.com/4aKv/

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the G string is rattling in the nut of your guitar.

Have you changed the strings since you purchased the instrument? Sometimes, fitting lower gauge (diameter) strings result in more space to vibrate within the string-groove of the nut, hence the rattle.

Alternatively, if the instrument is cheaply made (no disrespect!), the nut may have split, not have been fitted correctly, or expanded some other way.

I recommend you take it to a trusted luthier, or your place of purchase, and discuss installing a new nut (thankfully, these can be one of the cheapest parts of the guitar to replace, but best to leave to a professional unless you know what you're doing, to avoid damaging the neck or top of the fingerboard).

For a short term fix until you can solve the issue long term;

- detune the guitar one half step, capo at fret 1, and play as if the capo was the open position. The capo stops the string vibrating over the nut

or

- fit a capo just behind the nut, with light downward pressure, holding the offending rattling string down and reducing rattle for the time being (you may need to re-tune)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well yeah, it's the G string. I changed my strings not that long ago, like before 2 weeks, and the problem was before that, thought changing will help. Well the strings sound better of course, but the problem still exists :\. Since I don't have a capo, i'll take it to the luthier. Hopefully the fixing won't take very much time :D. Thanks for help though, at least I'll know it's not my strings to blame.

Comment: **If** it's a **junky** guitar and you want a quick **ugly** fix, I have found that you can use artfully cut and folded plastic (like that of a milk jug) or paper (folded more than once) at the slot in the nut underneath the string to secure a string.

Comment: @amalgamate I've used blu-tac/adhesive putty before to hold the string in place. Not included in my answer because any professional would laugh...and it looks silly!

Comment: Yep, but I have a few "beach" guitars. (guitars I willingly take to the beach). :-)